# How can I turn a regular function into a promise/async await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I've been reading about promises and async/await and such.

But I am bit confused when I have to combined these in certain points and with Typescript as well.

Look at this for instance, which is a functionality to show/hide a modal:

```
  // myStore.ts

  @action
  openDialog (body?: React.ReactElement): void {
    this.modalConfig.open = true;
    this.modalConfig.body = body;
  }
```

See?

There I would like to give the option to use asyn await when I call this method.

Let's say like this:

```
  const fn = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await myStore.openDialog(
      <SomeComp onFinish={() => myStore.closeDialog()} />
    );

    someOtherFn();
  };

...
      <OtherComp
        someProp={
          async () => {
            await fn();
            someOtherFunction();
          }
        }
      />
```

But right now if I call it like above, it says that:

```
'await' has no effect on the type of this expression
```

Get my point?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything in your code is doing anything asynchronous. `await openDialog` doesn't have any asynchronous calls in it, it just sets two properties. If you remove all of the await/async keywords, does it work as expected?

Comment: You're most likely getting this since awaiting on `fn` is returning undefined -  does `myStore.openDialog` return a promise like the code states?

Comment: You might be looking for `await new Promise(resolve => this.closeDialog = resolve); this.modalDialog.open = false; this.modalDialog.body = null;` in `openDialog`. But that's not a very idiomatic way to deal with stores in react(?).

Answer (score 0):

Async/await won't do much (if anything at all) in this kind of situation. To really use async/await effectively, you should use it in situations where delay is involved (such as an HTTP request or a database query)

As for the error you are receiving, your function must have return statement at the bottom and the returned value must be a promise

```js
const fn = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await myStore.openDialog(
    <SomeComp onFinish={() => myStore.closeDialog()} />
  );

  someOtherFn();
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Handle promise here
  })
};

...
    <OtherComp
      someProp={
        async () => {
          await fn();
          someOtherFunction();
        }
      }
    />
```